# Applying a certain style to all child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

So I have a tag called "svg" whose "visibility" property gains the value "hidden" whenever I hit a button (it's a toggle that works on the "div" containing it, svg only has inherit). Now, this "svg" elements has literally hundreds of child tags ("g" tags), most of which, for reasons I'm not going to explain, had a overwriting "visibility:visible" in their properties.

I edited all of them manually one by one (find and replace), but it was kind of a slog. Isn't there a command or a function that I can use so that ALL child elements of a certain tag (in this case "svg") will have the property "visibility:inherit"?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and CODE

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try it on your own. This community is to help people when they stuck with actual implementation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could go with:

```
svg * {
   visibility:inherit!important;
}
```

`!important` is really important there because if some of `<g>` had inline style this will give this style higher priority.

But I am not sure that all svg elements will accept this property, styling svg elements is little bit different than everything else.

If you would like to apply this directly as inline style you would have to use jQuery as below.

```
$('svg *').each(function() {
  $(this).css('visibility','inherit');
})
```

Comment: Yeah, the first worked! 
    g *{ 
    visibility:inherit!important;
    }
    
    svg * {
    visibility:inherit!important;
    }
    
    div {
    visibility:inherit;
    }

Comment: It was probably downvoted because it's not a good answer. Using !important with * is force feeding that property to everything under the element and that's not a good thing to do. Especially using "inherit", it just seems odd but I haven't really looked at the question. Your answer may "work" but it might not be a good solution.